# this.setState is not a function error is persistent even though I have followed many examples that use the same code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am new to React, and am trying to fill my components state with data stored on my mongodb Database.

I am using this call to fetch my data:

```
class DisplayPrograms extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setState = { programs: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/programs")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.setState({ programs: response.data });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

render() { .....
```

My render() function (not included) is working, and my console.log(response.data) outputs an array of objects like it is supposed to as you can see below, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Array [ {…}, {…} ]
DisplayProducts.jsx:15
_________________________________________________

TypeError: "this.setState is not a function"
    componentDidMount DisplayProducts.jsx:16
DisplayProducts.jsx:19
```

I'm sure it's a quick fix but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: In your constructor can you change this.setstate to this.state.

Comment: I posted the solution below but since your new to React I wanted to recommend React functional components and using React hooks for lifecycle methods, state, etc.. There are differing opinions on this but classes can get really cumbersome in React when your application gets large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constructor should look like this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { programs: [] };
  }
```

You were using `this.setState()` in the constructor instead of `this.state`
[Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) are the docs on this which show the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In `constructor` you need to create the initial state, so you need something like:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    programs: []
  }
}
```

The `this.setState` function you can use anywhere else.